# Adding manual schema (rich snippet) code to wordpress website( template) without yoast

Tags: schema, json-ld

we are working on SEO for one of the content related (article, videos) website and using wordpress template to build the website. Now if I use yoast generated schema the standard webpage schema is being used to all the pages which I really don't want and won’t be useful. I need to insert the schema according to the page category that can be manually coded (json-ld) or using any plugin that supports category wise schema uploading.

Please help me how to add schema code manually to wordpress website each page or any plugin that will help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use to Custom Fields.
you need add your schema code to article and Video Custom field and choose that on every post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).